# grgit log to get equivalent of git log --name-status --reverse --pretty=format:'%H'

Tags: jgit, grgit

How can I use grgit to obtain changed paths for a commit?

In the code below I get a grgit Commit object which has metadata about the commit but not the list of files modified.  I want to get the equivalent of `git log --name-status --reverse --pretty=format:'%H'`

Any ideas on transforming a commit sha into a grgit or jgit object with details about path and modification type?

```
    def commits =  grgit.log {
        range('sha', 'HEAD')
    }
    commits.each { def change ->
        def description = grgit.describe { commit = change }
        println description
        println change
    }
```

Comment: This post answers how to get the changes made by a commit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39935160/how-to-use-jgit-to-get-list-of-changes-in-files Does that help to get you started?

Comment: Thanks, I found a solution using jgit.  The object with commit info for grgit doesn't seem designed for my usecase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grgit is fine for what it does and it also brings with it jgit + provides access to that lower layer

So, we can do this

## Get a list of RevCommit Object for a range

```
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git
import org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.TreeWalk
import org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffFormatter
import org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.CanonicalTreeParser
import org.eclipse.jgit.diff.DiffEntry
import org.eclipse.jgit.treewalk.filter.PathFilter

def getCommits(def early, def later='HEAD') {
  Git git = grgit.repository.jgit
  def earliest =  git.repository.resolve(early)
  def latest = git.repository.resolve(later)

  return git.log()
        .addRange(earliest, latest)
        .call()
}
```

## Get diff info per commit

```
for (def commit in getCommits(earliestCommitId, latestCommitId)) {
    for (DiffEntry diffEntry in diffCommitWithParent(commit, pathFilter)) {
         println diffEntry // you'd want to do something more useful here
    }
}

def diffCommitWithParent(def commit, def pathFilter) {
  Git git = grgit.repository.jgit
  def previousTree = commit.getParentCount() > 0 ? commit.getParent(0).getTree() : null
  def currentTree = commit.getTree()
  def reader = git.repository.newObjectReader()
  def treeParserPrevious = new CanonicalTreeParser(null, reader, previousTree)
  def treeParserCurrent = new CanonicalTreeParser(null, reader, currentTree)
  return git.diff()
        .setOldTree(treeParserPrevious)
        .setNewTree(treeParserCurrent)
        .setPathFilter(new PathFilter(pathFilter))
        .call()
}
```